# Adding and Removing Dynamic Buttons From one activity to another activity in android on click of button from previous activity button click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget, android-button

I want to develop a similar kind of app(link below)
[How to create Button Dynamically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082432/how-to-create-button-dynamically-in-android)
But at the same time I want to display this in another activity and not in the same activity.
there are 2 edit text:
1) Button Name to be Created.
2) Destination address (for message to be send on creation of new button).
whose text is getting passed to another activity for the new button creation.

when I wrote

```
 public void onClick(View v) {    
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub    
        final Context context1=this;    
               if(v.getId()==R.id.button4){    
     LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);      
  // R.id.layout is the layout id of the xml file for the 2nd activity.    
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(context1,PCode.class);    
    Button b = new Button(this);    
    l1.addView(b);    
    startActivity(intent1);    

 }
```

The activity is not moving to the 2nd activity and the program is terminating. 
I am able to create new button when doing in the same activity.
Kindly Help .

Comment: How can you create the layout of Activity B in Activity A? Its gruesome.

Answer (score 0):

In the first activity's onClick send the data using Intent:

```
intent = new Intent(this, PCode.class);
        intent.putExtra("EXTRA_BTN_NAME", editText.getText());
        intent.putExtra("EXTRA_WHERE", where);
        startActivity(intent);
```

In the new activity you should get the data with

```
  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activty2);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String btnName = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_BTN_NAME");
    where= intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_WHERE");

LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);     
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context1,PCode.class);    
Button b = new Button(this);    
b.SetText(btnName);
//TODO - use the "where" parameter
l1.addView(b);
```

Comment: @baranS in 1st activity I have: 2 edit text and 1 button , i want to take the value of 1st editText which will be used as new  Button(android:text)[act1: MyAct,act2:PCode,xml1 linearlayout_id:layout1,xml2 linearlayout_id: layout2] . Will the above code work.(what is Consts.Extra_BTN_NAME,btnName)

Comment: I edited the answer: use the editText.getText() and send it with the intent extra. The Consts.Extra_BTN_NAME is just a Const with string, I replaced it in the answer

Comment: Extra_WHERE will be the location of next activity (PCode.class) ?

Comment: **Thank You So Much** i tried the above code and it works  .. is it possible to add buttons in the fixed size consisting of 3 buttons each in a row . How I must set Up the alignments ?

Comment: It's possible. First make sure that the LinearLayout has android:orientation="Horizontal". LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout .LayoutParams(
     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   b.setLayoutParams(lp);

Comment: I tried the code that was given by you at first. the button is created but when i go back to the previous activity the and redoing the same process then the 1st dynamic button is unavailable. eg: 1st  time: I added "ABC" then I go back and Add "XYZ" for the 2nd time , only XYZ button exist and not ABC.. Can to tell me in precise manner as I am new to android.

Comment: You're creating a new button each time. If you need to save them, you should keep an array of strings with the names and locations in the preferences. If you need more help with preferences, let me know. Since the answer solved the initial question, I would really appreciate it if you accepted the answer.

Comment: I would highly appreciate if u can help. As I am new to it you may also provide some tutorial(book). Below is the link which states that how my app must work but everything is dynamically done . Kindly help. I have searched here and there from past 3 days Will be gratefull to you if you can help. I tried adding one layout after another but only the 1st layout is displayed . **Kindly go through the link below**[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17082900/dynamic-creation-of-layout-textviews-and-orientation-with-dynamic-button-creatio]

Comment: ![My App][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9MD65.png my app work in this manner. kindly help or suggest to read some pdf to solve this. I already have the layout as below can  i add layouts dynamically in id= layout2 which is within the pcode.xml

Comment: I will answer the other question in its own place. Please consider accepting this answer and hopefuly we'll be able to chat

Comment: ![My App][1] [1]: i.stack.imgur.com/9MD65.png this is what i wnt to create, adding and removing buttons . I have taken 4 activities 1) home page , 2)the edit boxes for info and consisting one button,3) for button creation , 4) removing button , I am new on StackOvrflow kindly tell me how we will be able to chat so that i can cnslt you .@baronS

Comment: You need more reputation to chat. I'll look at the other question in its place

Answer (score 0):

You can pass total 3 message through intent for every button 1) Button Name to be Created. 2) Destination address (for message to be send on creation of new button). 3) Button Action (add/remove)
While in new activity you handle button action using our 3rd message of intent i.e. Button Action (add/remove) what action they want to perform. While in new activity you can handle using below code

```
  boolean isAddButton = getIntent().getBooleanExtra("ButtonAction", false);
            if(isAddButton){
             Button myButton = new Button(this);
             myButton.setText("Add Me");
             LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
             LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
             ll.addView(myButton, lp);
            }else{
             Button myButton = new Button(this);
             myButton.setText("Remove Me");

             LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
             LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
             ll.removeView(myButton, lp);
       }
```

Comment: I already have this layout for activity 2 & button is created on click from act1  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:id="@+id/layout"
   >

  <LinearLayout android:weightSum="100">
 <TextView  
 android:layout_weight="30"/>
     <ImageButton
     android:id="@+id/IButton2"
         />
     </LinearLayout>
        <ScrollView
  android:id="@+id/scrl">
  <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/layout2"/>
  </ScrollView></LinearLayout>