# Add button permanently from within app

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, button

I want my app to provide a function to add a button like described by Avadhani Y in [How to create Button Dynamically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082432/how-to-create-button-dynamically-in-android)

I copied this code and the button appears when I press the +-symbol but it isn't permanent. When I close the app and open it again, the button disappears.

For a minimal working example I

- created a Blank Android Application Project set up by Eclipse
- added part of the method described in [How to create Button Dynamically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082432/how-to-create-button-dynamically-in-android) to MainActivity.java (The second case with the minusbutton generates several error messages, so I left it out.):

  ```
  public void onClick(View v){

       switch(v.getId()){
       case (R.id.plusbutton):
                   Button myButton = new Button(this);
                   myButton.setText("Add Me");

                   LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
                   LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                   ll.addView(myButton, lp);
                   break;
      }
  }
  ```
- imported the necessary packages. Actually I'm not sure whether I chose the right one for the line with the LayoutParams - eclipse listed several packages - I chose `android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams`
- changed the activity_main.xml file to the one below.
- added some strings to the strings.xml file

My activity_main.xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.button_test.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

    <Button 
         android:id="@+id/plusbutton"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:onClick="onClick"
         android:text="@string/plus"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you can't save to resources such as `layout` files at runtime. So, your options (AFAIK) are to save the params and attributes of the `Button` into a db or other persistent storage then check at startup each time to recreate the `Button`. This would be very cumbersome, I would imagine, and very error-prone if not careful.

Another option, if there is a finite number of `Button`s available to be made, is to simply create them in your xml then use the `visibility` attribute to change from `gone`/`invisible` to `visible` when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Android is "stateless" - in other words, unless you "save" changes, they are discarded. What you need to do is include a way to persist any changes that you expect to survive beyond the user's immediate interaction with your app. Also, you should assume that any change might be discarded immediately afterward - in other words, don't "wait" to save changes. If the user's phone rings, your app might go to the background and get killed before `onPause` or `onStop` or `onDestroy` are ever called.

Look into saving a "flag" for the visibility of the button into `SharedPreferences` and then read the flag in `onCreate` or `onStart` or `onResume`. It's likely you could use any of these, but you will find that sometimes one or another works best (or one doesn't work right at all).

Comment: onPause and onStop are guaranteed to be called, starting from 3.0. That is, the system won't kill the process until after these two callbacks have completed.

Comment: my comment wasn't based on the docs exactly - I can assure you that `onPause` is not called when the battery dies. However, if you go by the docs, `onPause` is the only "non-killable" method call (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) but even the docs recommend "more aggressive" data storage. Seems to me they make that recommendation for a reason.

Comment: onStop is also non-killable. That is, the "killable" part of the documentation says what can happen after the callback is complete.

Comment: The reference I just posted states that `onStop` is killable only pre-Honeycomb. My observation is that if your app is taking up a lot of memory and the phone rings, Android might kill it before `onPause` is called given the critical nature of an incoming call.