# Dynamically Set ID to a Button in Android

Tags: android, android-resources

I want to dynamically create a button but am having an issue when it comes to setting an ID for it. I tried putting an integer value in there but keep getting an error that says `"Expected Resource of Type ID."` The issue is that I DONT want to create this Button in my XML file and yet I need a way to track it with an ID. Please Help.

```
Button changeButton = new Button(getApplicationContext());
changeButton.setText("Change");
changeButton.setId(1);//Keep Getting an error here
```

Comment: Needs to be associated to a layout. You can look at :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082432/how-to-create-button-dynamically-in-android

Comment: "yet I need a way to track it with an ID" -- I am not quite certain why, as you could track it via a tag or via ordinary Java collections (e.g., a `HashMap`). You can also define an ID resource (e.g., `res/values/ids.xml`, with `<item type="id" name="button_id">1</item>` elements) and use that ID (`R.id.button_id`, in this case).

Comment: But I think its not a error my be a warning in IDE.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In your res/values folder you can keep an ids.xml file, where you can define:

```
<resources>
   <item type="id" name="your_button_id"/>
   ...
</resources>
```

Then, you can use it in your code:

```
changeButton.setId(R.id.your_button_id);
```

Comment: I have a quick follow up, once this button is set. changeButton.setId(R.id.your_button_id); The App then goes on to create a number of buttons in the same fashion, all with different IDs. Let's say I now want to click on my original button and have it do something. How can I make this happen dynamically again? My first thought was to have a number of Button Variables that point to these IDs and place .SetOnClickListeners() to each but them seems to verbose. Is there a way of having one btn.setOnClickListener and have the btn somehow link to whatever ID you created in your res/values folder?

Comment: Why do you think it's verbose to .setonclicklistener on each button object? Are you saying you have the same functionality, in which case you could iterate through the button objects and set the same listener implementation? I'm not sure this may be the best overall approach for your particular problem.

Answer (score 8):

If your goal is to track it, you could try [setTag](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)):

```
 changeButton.setTag("any_tag");
```

Notice that the tag is of type Object, meaning it could be any object you want (String, int, Date, CustomeObject, ...etc).