# Project doesn't build when setting a View id of 1 or 100

Tags: android

I have added a Button and TextView using the Design view of Android Studio. I set the id for the Button to be 1 and the TextView to 100. When I try to build the project it errors out with error:  expected and error illegal start of type. This works if I programmatically set the id by using setId(1).

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/1"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
    android:text="1"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/locationBox" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/101"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/1" />
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because value for `android:id` can't be an integer. The value of `android:id` will be converted as an integer variable name in `R.java`. An integer can't be used as variable name.

Instead of `setId()` you need to use [setTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object)) and [findViewWithTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object)).

---

UPDATE

if you look at the `setId()` [source code](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/View.java#L21686):

```
/**
 * Sets the identifier for this view. The identifier does not have to be
 * unique in this view's hierarchy. The identifier should be a positive
 * number.
 *
 * @see #NO_ID
 * @see #getId()
 * @see #findViewById(int)
 *
 * @param id a number used to identify the view
 *
 * @attr ref android.R.styleable#View_id
 */
public void setId(@IdRes int id) {
    mID = id;
    if (mID == View.NO_ID && mLabelForId != View.NO_ID) {
        mID = generateViewId();
    }
}
```

You will find that `setId()` is not setting the id of View but the value id of the View. This is related with [generateViewId()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#generateViewId()):

> Generate a value suitable for use in setId(int). This value will not
>   collide with **ID values** generated at build time by aapt for R.id.

Comment: how come button.setId(1) works then? does it consider 1 as a string (even though is (int id))?

Comment: ok i think that makes sense. So, for my app, I will have a nonset number of shots. When I am creating a button for these shots (in my code), is it better to use     setId() or     setTag()? This Id/Tag will tell the program which shot number the user is on because they will all use the same onClick function that pulls in the shot number (via     getId() or     getTag()) and updates an array. (If this is off topic, I apologize)

Comment: @SamwiseTheBrave: you can use `android:tag="` for your case for using a set of number. Then you can use `findViewWithTag()`. Take a look https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#Tags

Answer (score 0):

Give like this

```
 android:id="@+id/button1"
```

dont use setid(1) also, to track a view use like

```
button.setTag() and retrieve using button.geTag()
```

Comment: So the thing is, I am creating a virtual scorecard for archery shoots. I was planning on using the id as a way to identify which shot number they are on. Also, what is the difference between setId and setTag?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127881/dynamically-set-id-to-a-button-in-android