# A button to create an object on android Studio

Tags: android

How can we create a button with a command to create an other object on Android ?

i mean, i press the button on the app and it create in the layout, a new object, for exemple a textView.

how could i proceed ?

thanks !

Comment: Better way is, make that textView in xml file first make it's view GONE and on Button Click make it visible

Comment: Serach on  google for how to add View Dynamically in Android .

Comment: Have you try my post ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way:

First you defined into your xml file a layout parent for your TextView and get it in your code:

`final LinearLayout parentView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_view_id);`

Then you define create your TextView for example:

```
final TextView textView = new TextView(context);

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                ); // set height and width
                textView.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom); // set margin if necessary
                textView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

and in your listener :

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override public void onClick(View view) {
                parentView.addView(textView);
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: it just cannot resolve (context) 

and for parentView.addView(textView); it says both variables are accessed from within inner class and must be declared

Comment: context is a general word to define your context , if you are in activity instead of `context` you put `this`, if you are in fragment you put `getActivity`

Comment: @CG_corp See if my edit is helping you, i add the final key word for the parentview and the textview

Comment: when i try, my app crash

Comment: What is the issue ?

Comment: i don't know, the code is well, no error, the app start, the command is on a second activity and i when i start it, the app crash 

the activity is registered in the manifest so i actually don't know what's happening

Comment: Have you look the logcat ?

Comment: yes, i had "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first." i added a removeView, i don't have this anymore. but now when i want to go back to my first activity, it take a little while and i can guess with the logcat that it restart.

Comment: In the android monitor, just after the crash change "Show only selected application" by "No filter" , change debug level with error level and try to find the log of your application.

Comment: at android.view.ViewGroup.resetResolvedLayoutDirection(ViewGroup.java:6393)

Comment: ok, there is a lot of errors (758 precisely) in the ViewGroup, i don't know why but i think the troubles comes from here

Comment: Add a image with the error log , not the 758 logs ^^

Comment: correction : 762 :D 

a lot of methods, import... are "cannot resolve" 

in fact, all of the errors are

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild the project

Answer (score 0):

first of all create a click listener on your button

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

      }
    }
```

and then this with add a new textview into your target layout

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("hello word!");
tv.setTextSize(18);
tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
tv.setClickable(true);
tv.setPadding(0, 10, 0, 0);
tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
mainLayout.addView(tv);
```

in this ex `mainLayout` is the view that you want to add new object like textview, ....

Comment: ok, thanks ! an i can use this method even for other kind of objects like Button or ImageButton ?

Comment: uhm, for button http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082432/how-to-create-button-dynamically-in-android

Comment: i have a lot of errors

i have a "cannot resolve" on each "set" (padding, TextSize, Clickable...)

"unknown class" for the conditions in TextColor and Clickable


and "method does not override method from its superclass"


clearly there's something missing with so much errors but i don't know why.

Comment: I'v update my answer a little bit, just add the code and import any library that is needed, for ex Gravity, Text-view, ...

Comment: this is the simplest code in android! I think your problem is some where else