# Same Java file for two layouts (XML)

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 2 layouts for my application
but I have written all my Logic in MainActivity.JAVA

I want to use MainActivity.JAVA for my other layout (XML) file also

How can I do that?

This is my MainActivity.XML (Layout File)

[image: This is main Layout file]

Now I want Blue Button on Right to resize the new layout for that

New XML (with no Java file) only Layout file

[image: This is another Layout File]

Now I want to use the same Java file (MainActivity.JAVA)
For this new layout file

Comment: You can load whatever you want via `setContentView()`... What's the exact problem?

Comment: Think of it the other way round. You don't use a Java file for a layout for you use a layout in an `Activity` or `Fragment`. Find the place where you inflate it and based on some condition inflate the other one.

Comment: I want to use same java file for 2 layouts

Comment: Why two layouts? You can dynamically hide and show Views from one layout

Comment: Why don't you create/set button positions from java file dynamically?

Comment: Can u please help me out i Don't know how to set @VVB

Comment: @cricket_007 how can i do that

Comment: Sample reference link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082432/how-to-create-button-dynamically-in-android

Comment: You put the black area in the initial layout, set `android:visibility="gone"`, then you can use `setVisibility()` method on that view in Java from the button click

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `Fragment` or another solution is that `include` layout. You said you have one common activity and in this activity you need to include two XML layout then you can set like this:-

You can use the include element to have sub-XML files:

**main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout ... >
    <include layout="@layout/file1" />
    <include layout="@layout/file2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**file1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@color/toolbar_color">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_toolbar_left"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

            <TextView
             android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
             android:layout_centerInParent="true"
             android:ellipsize="end"
             android:gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:padding="10dp"
             android:singleLine="true"
             android:text="MyApp"
             android:textColor="@color/white"
             android:textSize="20sp"
             android:textStyle="bold" />
      </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**file2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_splash"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    tools:context="com.inducesmile.androidmusicplayer.SplashActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/logomusic"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two XML files, you can merge both of them by including one into another.

For example: if you have two files named a.xml and b.xml, then you can include the b.xml in a.xml using ***include*** tag like

```
<include layout="@layout/b.xml" />
```

Then call setContentView (R.layout.a) in your MainActivity.java

Or, you can make use of Fragments.

Answer (score 0):

In your main activity layout, you could use a `FrameLayout`, which you can then add a fragment to. Then in the Java file, you can use `getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace()` method to inflate the layout XMLs as and when you like.